# Using text-overflow ellipsis in middle of list items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement HTML/CSS where there are four list items (`li`) within a full-width unordered list element (`ul`), but am struggling to get one of those items to use the `text-overflow:ellipsis` command.

The result should be something along these lines...

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Item One | Item Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two ...  | Item Three | Item Four |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The 1st, 3rd and 4th items are to be locked in position - with the 1st item on the left, and the 3rd and 4th items "locked" to the right hand side of the full-width area.

The 2nd item should take all the remaining space, with `...` ellipsis on the overflow.

This area will be used within a responsive design, and therefore will expand/shrink depending on the available screen area.

*All* four of the items will contain variable amounts of text, however the 2nd item will always have the most.  So the 1st, 3rd and 4th should always be fully visible... but the 2nd should hide what doesn't fit.

This the the closest I've got (using two `ul` controls, floating the 3rd and 4th items on the right hand side), but as soon as I add the CSS for the 2nd item, it all goes wrong.  (By "wrong", I mean the 2nd item wraps onto the next line rather than staying on the same line and showing the `...`)

```css
#leftul {
    width:100%;
}
#rightul {
    float:right;
}
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#leftul #leftlarge {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<ul id="rightul">
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
</ul>
<ul id="leftul">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li id="leftlarge">Item Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two</li>
</ul>
```

Can anybody please suggest how this could be possible to acheive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is working fine, try this way

```
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="middle"><div  class="flexible_width1">Item Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two</div></div>
```

Css:

```
.left{
    background:red;
    min-width:70px;
    float:left;

}
.middle{
    background:yellow;

}
.right{
    float:right;
    min-width:70px;
    background:green
}
.flexible_width1 {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L7y0mmy4/)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the 1st, 3rd and 4th items will have variable text in them (they will not always be the same, and therefore I can't set a fixed width)

Comment: @freefaller you can use min-width  for 1st, 3rd and 4th items

Comment: Think you might be on to something here!

Comment: If you want to add text-overflow:ellipsis; for only one item, then this will fix your issue.

Comment: Excellent - **exactly** what I was looking for. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

use this code with j query

```
#table {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        table-layout: fixed;
    }

        #table > div {
            display: table-cell;
        }

            #table > div:first-child {
                display: inline-block;
                background: red;
            }

            #table > div:nth-child(2) {
                width: 100%;
                background: yellow;
                overflow: hidden;
                white-space: nowrap;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
            }

            #table > div:nth-child(3) {
                display: inline-block;
                background: aqua;
            }

            #table > div:nth-child(4) {
                display: inline-block;
                background: lightgray;
            }
```

HTML

```
<div id="table">
    <div>first</div>
    <div>second second second second second second second second </div>
    <div>third</div>
    <div>fourth</div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var first_row = $('#table>div:first-child').width();
        $('#table>div:first-child').css('width', first_row + 'px')
        $('#table>div:first-child').css('display', 'table-cell')

        var first_row1 = $('#table>div:nth-child(3)').width();
        $('#table>div:nth-child(3)').css('width', first_row1 + 'px')
        $('#table>div:nth-child(3)').css('display', 'table-cell')

        var first_row2 = $('#table>div:nth-child(4)').width();
        $('#table>div:nth-child(4)').css('width', first_row2 + 'px')
        $('#table>div:nth-child(4)').css('display', 'table-cell')

    })
```

Comment: If you're going to use the code from somebody else's answer as the basis of your answer, at least give them credit! Just digesting what you've written

Comment: This is a very interesting idea... I'm currently seeing if I can integrate it into my current solution

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but an answer has been provided that does do it purely in CSS

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `width` to the element.

```css
#leftul {
    width:100%;
}
#rightul {
    float:right;
}
ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#leftul #leftlarge {
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:40%;
}
```

```html
<ul id="rightul">
    <li>Item Three</li>
    <li>Item Four</li>
</ul>
<ul id="leftul">
    <li>Item One</li>
    <li id="leftlarge">Item Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hmmm... then that could be a problem.  The area is supposed to be "full width", i.e. in responsive design, the 2nd item should be taking up all the available space, with the 3rd and 4th items "locked" to the right hand side

Comment: @freefaller use overflow:hidden; means width fix right ?

Comment: Sorry @Lalji, I don't understand. Are you asking a question, or making a statement disguised as a question?

Answer (score 2):

If by `locked` you mean that the elements will have a `fixed` width,then you can use `display:table/table-cell` to achieve that:

```css
body{margin: 0}

#table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#table>div{
    display:table-cell;
}

#table>div:first-child{
    width: 100px;
    background:red;
}

#table>div:nth-child(2){
    width: 100p%;
    background:yellow;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

#table>div:nth-child(3){
    width: 100px;
    background:aqua;
}

#table>div:nth-child(4){
    width: 100px;
    background:lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
    <div>first</div>
    <div>second second second second second second second second </div>
    <div>third</div>
    <div>fourth</div>
</div>
```

Where the second cell will always take the full remaining width.

[Check the fiddle to se on responsive](http://jsfiddle.net/cgkuqdt1/)

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like I've been vague - when I mean locked, I meant locked to the left or right of the full-width area.  The 1st/3rd/4th items will have variable length content in them.  But this is much closer... if I can figure out how to make it work with variable content

Comment: @freefaller What do you mean by "variable content"?

Comment: Sorry @Vucko, it appears that I'm having a bad day with my explanations.  This "full width area" will be used within a responsive design.  The four panels will hold different (variable) text in different situations, they will never be fixed text, therefore it's impossible for me to set a specific width on them.  I need the 1st, 3rd and 4th items to be as small as possible but with the text fully visible - and then the 2nd item to take up the rest of the space, hiding what doesn't fit (preferably with the `...` ellipsis.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: @freefaller now I get the picture :) unfortunately, without knowing the width of those items, I'd say that it's not possible do do that with pure CSS.

Comment: Sigh, that's what I was afraid of... just digesting the answer by Lalji (who appears to have copied your answer as the base to theirs)

Comment: @freefaller well, if he'd copied mine then that means mine answer isn't bad :D
All jokes aside, if you're okay with using JS then [here's a little fix for your situation](http://jsfiddle.net/cgkuqdt1/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your effort - turns out there is a [way of doing it via CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32313009/930393)

Comment: @freefaller well, I didn't believed that it can be doen with CSS only . Every day you learn something new :)

Comment: As my late grandmother used to say, "you learn something new every day, if you're not careful!" ;-)

Comment: @freefaller words of wisdom! :)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this can help you: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oo60o01d/)

```
<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul>
        <li>Item One</li>
        <li>Item Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two Two</li>
        <li>Item Three</li>
        <li>Item Four</li>
    </ul>
</div>

#navcontainer ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
}

#navcontainer ul li 
{ 
    display: inline-block;
    border:1px solid black; 

    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

It should be what you are looking for :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it neither take up the full width of the screen/area, nor does the 2nd item expand to use all available space.